# will_paginate for results of method on an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm working on a rails app that searches on a database of users. Because the search is fairly complex I have a search model that stores the different search parameters and a results method in that model that actually puts together the query and returns an array of objects.

Since there is no relationship between search and the objects returned in results, is it still possible to paginate the results with will_paginate? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do what you do, without needing to paginate the array.  According to the docs:

```
# paginate in Active Record now returns a Relation
Post.where(:published => true).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')

# the new, shorter page() method
Post.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
```

(( from https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki ))

... so you should be able to create your "where" even as a model method and then paginate the results of the model method.

You can paginate the array, if you absolutely have to, according to these instructions:

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility#willpaginatecollection